# Flutter StreamSubscription does not print

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to ask why my streamsubscription does not print anything

I use `StatefulWidget` and declare StreamSubscription

```
StreamSubscription _triggerOrder;
```

and then I put my function on init state

```
@override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    _triggerOrder=firestore.collection('users').document(widget.idUser).snapshots().listen((trigger){
      print("PENDING==========> "+trigger.data['pending']);
      if(trigger.data['pending'] == true && _oderTrigger == false){
        _modalBottomSheetMenu(context);
        setState(() {
          _oderTrigger = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to show modal if the data pending from firebase is true. And when I try to print, it does not print the pending.

Comment: Please check your userID, it should same as firebase

Comment: i already double check for it sir

Comment: widget.idUser: what it giving you? Does it return an exception?

Comment: only from testing, from login form, i put an ID from `document` in firebbase, and it will show based from the idUser